# substitute shorter element name for span?

Tags: html

Wondering if I can substitute different html element tag names and get the original behavior?

For example, could I represent `<span/>` elements as `<s/>` and get the same behavior and affordances of `<span/>`?  I am imagining some sort of xslt-esque javascript mapping.  Not even sure this is a good idea.  I am open to being told this is a bad idea.

Why?  I have a big bucket of span tags and would like to reduce my page sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea. Stick to HTML.

> I have a big bucket of span tags and would like to reduce my page sizes.

Use HTTP compression. Repeated chunks of content (such as `<span` and `</span>`) compress very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to reduce page sizes, I would not be looking at this technique (if it's even possible), instead I would format the source code to remove all unnecessary characters (extra spaces add data to be loaded and increase the doc size). Also, make sure your css is a streamlined as possible for example..

If you have many duplicate classes that have to have unique ids, rather than having:

```
 uniqueclass1{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:#999;
 }

 uniqueclass2{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:#999;
 }
```

You can reduce this to:

```
 uniqueclass1,
 uniqueclass2{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:#999;
 }
```

This will help to reduce the size.